# Is Stata Turing-complete?

Tags: loops, stata, turing-complete

I have been doing some statistics work with Stata recently and not enjoying it very much.

It doesn't feel to me like it's a "proper" programming language: in particular I don't *think* there's a way to loop until a condition is met.

Am I right in my feeling, or is Stata truly Turing-complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard of Stata before but the webpage brags that it has "[if, while](http://www.stata.com/capabilities/)" and "[looping and branching](http://www.stata.com/capabilities/program.html)".

Wikibooks has [this example](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Stata/Natural_Language_Processing):

```
local k = 1
file open myfile using toto.txt, read text
file read myfile line
while r(eof) == 0 {
    local k = `k' + 1
    di "`k' `line'"
    file read myfile line
    }
file close myfile
```

I don't know what *"proper" programming language* means but at first glance it definitely appears to be Turing-complete.

Comment: Somehow I had completely missed the fact that Stata had a while loop! Thanks very much.

Comment: I don't know why "brag" is thought to be a suitable word here.

Answer (score 1):

A "proper" programming language in the sense that you could build a webpage or GUI with it? Of course not. But that's a bit extreme. You can certainly write loops with .ado and .do files; i would say it is turing complete.

Comment: You "could" build a webpage or GUI with it, though it's not an ideal platform for doing so & its pretty limited.  E.g., I can write the html for my webpage w. the -file- commands, write tables for my webpage using -estout- or -tabout- (from SSC), or write GUIs within the Stata environment using the -window- subcommands.  See the program/gui written from Stata (using Stata Numerics) for ADePt (http://tinyurl.com/stataadept) on the World Bank site.

Answer (score 1):

Stata's `ado` language has all the usual conditional statements:

- [if programming command](https://www.stata.com/manuals/pif.pdf)
- [if *exp* qualifier](https://www.stata.com/manuals/u11.pdf#u11.1.3)

However, it is important that one does not confuse the two:

- [if command versus if qualifier](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/if-command-versus-if-qualifier/)

In addition, Stata's `ado` language loop constructs include:

- for (an out-of-date command as of Stata 8)
- [foreach](https://www.stata.com/manuals/pforeach.pdf)
- [forvalues](https://www.stata.com/manuals/pforvalues.pdf)
- [while](https://www.stata.com/manuals/pwhile.pdf)

`Mata`, Stata's matrix programming language also supports:

- [if and else](https://www.stata.com/manuals/m.pdf#m-2if)
- [for](https://www.stata.com/manuals/m.pdf#m-2for)
- [while](https://www.stata.com/manuals/m.pdf#m-2while)

Consequently, both Stata's `ado` and `mata` programming languages appear to
satisfy the criteria for being characterized as Turing complete.

It is important to note though that these are **not** *general programming
languages*, but full-fledged *statistical languages*.

Answer (score 0):

While you can use the -while-, -if, -else- commands to perform looping until a condition is met, it's usually a better idea in Stata to use the -foreach- or -forvalues- loops in their place.
So, instead of saying:

```
while "`1'" != "" {
<do something>
}
```

or

```
if "`a'" == "" {
<do something>
}
else {
<do something else>
}
```

it's usually better (and more intuitive) to instead to do:

```
forvalues x = 1/100 {
<do something>
}
```

-- No -if-, -else-, or -break- conditions needed.  See -help forvalues- or -help foreach- in Stata for details.

---

^NOTE:  the while-else loop in my original post was removed--thanks for the heads-up, Keith.  The -else- part was intended for the if{] else{} loop example only.  Regardless, the point of my post wasn't to suggest the use of a while/else or if/else loop, it was that -foreach-/-forvalues- are usually a preferred approach.

Answer (score 0):

@eric.a.booth: I think your example is strange.  I'm not sure I've ever seen `while { ... } else {...}`

Also, note that Stata doesn't test the loop before you run it, and will allow itself to get caught in an infinite loop.

```
local x = 0
while `x'<5 {
   display `x' / 2
   local ++x
}
```

Comment: I fixed the while-else mistake in my post, thanks again.  I meant to have the -else- with the -if- example only.  <p>  For your second comment, I don't see how your example would put Stata into an infinite loop (?)  If you left out the macro expansion (++i or a -macro shift- or even a -continue, break- ) command then it would go into a infinite loop, but that would be in contrast to the guidelines of the user manual in [P]-while-.

Comment: I was trying to give a helpful example.  Thus, I was pointing out the need to use something like ++x (to avoid the infinite loop).